# Как вывести сообщение и запретить повторную отправку формы?

Tags: php

```
    if ($_POST["submit_save"])
    {
    if ($_SESSION['edit_tovar'] == '1')
    { 
      $error = array();
      
       if (empty($_POST["galleryimg"]))
      {        
      include("actions/upload-gallery.php"); 
      unset($_POST["galleryimg"]);                 
      }
                                                                           
       if (count($error))
       {           
            $_SESSION['message'] = "<p id='form-error'>".implode('<br />',$error)."</p>";     
       }else
       {           
       $querynew = "name='{$_POST["form_name"]}'";
       $update = mysql_query("UPDATE user_add_db SET $querynew WHERE id='$id'",$link);
             
       $_SESSION['message'] = "<p id='form-success'>Изменение успешно!</p>";
       
       header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
}
else
    {
       $msgerror = 'У вас нет прав!'; 
    }           
}
```

Как вывести это сообщение, чтоб header: location тоже сработало?

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "<p id='form-success'>Изменение успешно!</p>";
```

Comment: А что сейчас не так?

Comment: в шаблоне надо писать видимо `if (empty($_SESSION['message'])) echo $_SESSION['message'];`

Comment: Сейчас срабатывает header location но сообщение не выводится. А если убрать header location то сообщение выводится, но форма может быть отправлена повторно. Как сделать эти 2 действия последовательно, чтоб они работали?

Comment: Не может сообщение не выводится потому что оно лежит в сессии. Скорее всего ты его выводишь прямо в текущем коде, а надо в шаблоне

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было в конце добавить exit. И все заработало! Который раз сам задаю вопрос и сам нахожу решение :)

```
 header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
```